# What is the approximate range of the Pelegrin Tarragon?

Tags: aircraft-performance, ultralight, range

I recently read about [the Pelegrin Tarragon ultralight aircraft](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelegrin_Tarragon) made in my country, and got interested in it.

Is it possible to have a reasonable estimate of the average distance you could cover in such plane, taking into account that it has a cruising speed of 270km/h, a  96l fuel tank and the engine it uses (a single [Rotax 912ULS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotax_912)) is listed as using 15l/h at 5500rpm (75% power)?

Unfortunately, the manufacturer's page doesn't list any max distance or indeed any technical specs, and Wikipedia entry doesn't list much more either

Comment: @MichaelTracy dammit, that's what happens when looking from mobile. the manufacturer's page doesn't list range when viewing mobile version of the page. thanks.

Comment: Why is this a question when it can be so robustly obtained from a simple [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pelegrin+Tarragon+range&oq=Pelegrin+Tarragon+Range&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60.4799j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: That 15l/hr has to be at 60%.  At 75% the specific fuel consumption is under .4 lb/hp/hr, which seems to be a stretch, even for an efficient geared engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the manufacturer](http://www.tarragonaircraft.com/en/specs/), it has a range of 1,300km.

Answer (score 0):

A more reasonable fuel burn at 75% on the Rotax 912ULS is 18 Lph and with long range 250L option the Pelegrin has a no-reserve range of 3,750 km but few of us would enjoy sitting 13+ hrs in the cockpit. The longer range tanks were developed for a future military trainer incorporating a thirstier turboprop engine.

Comment: 13 hours... ***yikes!!!***  Nevertheless, welcome to Av.SE!